# xforms and getting a particular value from a list

Tags: xforms

There is a small code that works with appache tomcat and chiba-3.0.0b2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:events="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
<xhtml:head>
    <xforms:model>
```

there is instance where to get a dynamic list

```
        <xforms:instance id="xs">
            <xs>
                <x kd="1" name="one"></x>
                <x kd="2" name="two"></x>
                <x kd="3" name="three"></x>
                <!-- ... -->
            </xs>
        </xforms:instance>
    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
```

There is a switch-case construction

```
<xforms:switch>
```

list case

```
<xforms:case id="list">
    <xhtml:ul>
        <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('xs')/x">
            <xhtml:li>
                <xforms:trigger>
                    <xforms:toggle events:event="DOMActivate" case="onerec" />
                    <xforms:value ref="@kd" />
                    <xforms:label ref="@name" />
                </xforms:trigger>
            </xhtml:li>
        </xforms:itemset>
    </xhtml:ul>
</xforms:case>
```

one record case

```
<xforms:case id="onerec">
```

How to get a last submitted button value instead of '2' in formula [@kd=2] (i.e instead of [@kd=2] i like  @kd='clicked trigger value')???

```
    <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('xs')/x[@kd=2]">
        There are name "<xforms:label ref="@name" />" and id "<xforms:value ref="@kd" />"
    </xforms:itemset>
```

There is a back button

```
    <xforms:trigger>
```

opening the list case

```
                <xforms:toggle events:event="DOMActivate" case="list" />
                <xforms:label>Back</xforms:label>
            </xforms:trigger>
        </xforms:case>
    </xforms:switch>
</xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an instance to store the index of the actually clicked trigger, like this

```
<xforms:instance id="navigation">
          <data>
            <actual>1</actual>
          </data>
</xforms:instance>
```

Then set this index when clicking the trigger using the `set-value` action:

```
 <xforms:trigger>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">                   
        <xforms:toggle case="onerec" />
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('navigation')/actual" value="@kd"/>
    </xforms:action>

    <xforms:value ref="@kd" />
    <xforms:label ref="@name" />
 </xforms:trigger>
```

Then, to know the active case, use `instance('navigation')/actual`